# Copy/Pasting BibTeX into Endnote X9

Tags: bibtex, conversion, jabref, bibdesk

I have a BibTeX entry that I want to get into EndNote X9.

```
@article{mollerup2017controlling,
  title={Controlling sewer systems--a critical review based on systems in three EU cities},
  author={Mollerup, Ane Loft and Mikkelsen, Peter Steen and Thornberg, D and Sin, Gurkan},
  journal={Urban Water Journal},
  volume={14},
  number={4},
  pages={435--442},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

I'm able to copy and paste it into JabRef or BibDesk, but is there really no way to easily import it into EndNote without having to go through another software or downloading the reference? I guess I'm looking for a similar copy/paste behavior.

Comment: This is borderline off topic, since EndNote isn't a tool that interfaces with TeX in any usable way. JabRef can export `.ris` files that EndNote can import, I believe. See [Conversion of BibTeX to Endnote bibliography \[02/12/2015\]](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/227852)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is another case of trying to use software in a way it wasn't intended. Seems ridiculous that Endnote doesn't interface with LaTeX well, but that's something I'll have to take up with Clarivate.

Comment: @DiegotheBunny Well EndNote is proprietary software aimed primarily at Word users. TeX is such a small niche, is completely free and already has excellent citation software, so there's very little incentive for it EndNote to care about it at all.